# Django form for writing blogs

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-forms

As a beginner in Django I know how to create basic website for blogs, using a Django model of fields title and content... that's it.

But now I want to create a real dynamic blog form, which can have multiple sub headings, code blocks, text blocks, and images.

Or basically a blog form which can have random number of these kinds of blocks (field like code, text, image). And the user can add as many number of these blocks as required.

Also these blocks (or fields) which would be the part of the blog post, should be saved in the dataset in the same order as the user created.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you-

Note: I did not run this code. All the code was written by me in stackoverflow. Please forgive me for any typos.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    // and more fields if you want

    def blog_field_exists(self):
        return self.blogfield_set.count() > 0

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class BlogField(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    image_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True) // blank means image is 
    // optional
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Blog

{...}

class BlogDetailView(generic.DetailView)
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'app/blog_detail.html'
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>', views.BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='blog_view')
]
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

class BlogFieldInline(admin.TabularInline)
    model = BlogField
    extra = 1

class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [BlogFieldInline]

admin.site.register(BlogField)
admin.site.register(Blog, BlogAdmin)
```

templates/app/blog_detail.html

```
{...} // previous code

{% for blog in blog_list %}
<h1>{{blog.title}}</h1>
<p>{{blog.body}}</p>
{% if blog.blog_field_exists %}
    {% for field in blog.blogfield_set.all %}
        <div style="margin: 1rem 0;">
            <hr>
            <h4>{{field.title}}</h4>
            <p>{{field.body}}</p>
            <img src="{{field.image_url}}" alt="{{field.title}}" />
            <hr>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What is that image here - "admin.site.register(Image)", I can't get around that part, since in the models there's only Blog and BlogField.

Comment: Also I'm getting `TypeError: 'MediaDefiningClass' object is not iterable` on this line `admin.site.register(BlogAdmin, BlogAdmin)`.

Comment: Sorry I wrote admin.site.register(Image) by mistake. I've removed it now!

Comment: Try to run it now! I edited and removed all the errors I could find! Please let me know if you still get an error.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This time I'm getting `Generic detail view BlogDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.Generic detail view BlogDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.`

Comment: I'm extremely sorry! I forgot to add something! I've edited the code. Please try it now!

Comment: Sorry me I should have figured it out... Thanks man, it really helped.

Comment: No problem mate.

Answer (score 1):

A really simple and easy way of doing that is by adding a WYSIWYG editor package.

You have [Summernote](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote), [CKEditor](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor) and [Tinymice](https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce), that are the the most popular out there.

The installation of each of them is really easy and straightforward, so you won't have any problem with it.

You can also check the [djangopackages](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/wysiwyg/) website for everything you could need. It's a very good place to find things like comment section packages, newsletter, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, though I'd like to use them at last when I wouldn't be able to so by using pure Django. Still they are very helpful. Thanks again

Comment: well so I just recommend you use javascript and implement every function by yourself. Good luck!

Comment: actually javascript is done already, the only issue is how can I take that dynamically created data (blog) into a django model and then save it.